# Flexible parenthesing command

Tags: macros, optional-arguments

I would like to create a smart parenthesing command without using the xparse package.

```
\p(1)   prints  (1)
\p[1]           [1]
\p{1}           {1}
\p(1|2)         (1|2)
```

I tried this code but it doesn't work for braces.
Also, I don't know how to do `(1|2)`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

\def\p
{
    \@ifnextchar(
        {\@parenthesis}
        {
            \ifx\@let@token[
                \expandafter\@bracket
            \else
                \expandafter\@brace
            \fi
        }
}

\def\@parenthesis(#1){\left( #1 \right)}
\def\@bracket[#1]{\left[ #1 \right]}
\def\@brace#1{\left{ #1 \right}}

\makeatother


\begin{document}

$\p(1)$ 
$\p[1]$ 
$\p{1}$ 
$\p(1|2)$    
\end{document}
```

My motivation for doing this is to get a more expressive syntax.

Comment: Hmm, you might be able to do something with the `xparse` package

Comment: Is there any chance that your expressions will include nested parentheses, brackets, and/or braces?

Comment: @Mico Yes, I might do `\p[f(2)]`

Comment: @NicolasEssis-Breton Then you've lost; `\p(f(2))` won't work with any "reasonable" definition.

Comment: Note that defining such syntax (while possible) is explicitly against the latex syntax guidelines and as other constructs will not be expecting this syntax it's likely to lead to problems when combined with other code http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84685/the-rhyme-and-reason-of-function-argument-syntax-brackets-versus-braces/84704#84704

Comment: @egreg Maybe this deserves another question. Why are latex parsing rules so different than programming language parsing rules? Is it for compilation speed? In a python world say, `\p(f(2))` would be `\left( f(2) \right)`.

Comment: @NicolasEssis-Breton only `{}` groups form part of TeX's parsing rules (and are matched according to nesting depth `()` are just two unrelated characters TeX has no inbuilt knowledge that one is paired with the other and that is useful for notations such as `)a,b(`

Comment: @NicolasEssis-Breton TeX is a language for typesetting; while braces don't play an important role in typeset text, (round) parentheses do and in many situations they don't come in pairs. Other languages can do differently because they don't have as their main objective typesetting text.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This appears to work:

> *Update*: see further down a different implementation which does the `\left` and `\right` things and also is compatible with a `\middle`
>   in-between.
>
> *Second Update*: `mathcodes` do not have all the limitations of
>   catcodes. Based on `mathcodes` I propose one more approach which
>   is more powerful than the previous one: it allows (seemingly) very 
>   complicated nesting. I dream there were 
>   `textcodes`... the point is that `mathcodes` do not freeze. This is 
>   extremely useful.

*Edit*: correct restores of the `mathcodes` after
some additional work. I promise not to edit again...

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

\def\p{\afterassignment\p@aux\let\next=}

\def\p@aux{\ifx\next\bgroup\lbrace\bgroup\aftergroup\rbrace\else
               \expandafter\next\fi}

\makeatother


\begin{document}

$\p(1)$ 
$\p[1]$ 
$\p{1}$ 
$\p(1|2)$    
\end{document}
```

[image: parentheses]

With automatic `\left` and `\right`. Should I also do the middle thing?

Update: added missing ̀`%` at end lines and thinking about the e-TeX `\middle` thing which is causing me some problems...

> (see further down for the final method: `\middle` was quite a
>   challenge)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter

\def\p{\afterassignment\p@aux\let\next=}

\def\p@aux{\ifx\next\bgroup
             \left\lbrace\bgroup\aftergroup\right\aftergroup\rbrace
           \else
             \ifx\next(%
                   \left(\bgroup\catcode`\)=\tw@
                   \aftergroup\right\aftergroup)%
             \else
             \ifx\next[%
                   \left[\bgroup\catcode`\]=\tw@
                   \aftergroup\right\aftergroup]%
             \else\next
             \fi\fi
           \fi}

\makeatother


\begin{document}\thispagestyle{empty}

$\p(1) \p(\dfrac{1}{2})$

$\p[1] \p[\dfrac{1}{2}]$

$\p{1} \p{\dfrac{1}{2}}$

$\p(1|2) \p(\dfrac{1}{2}|3)$
\end{document}
```

[image: second]

---

Giving justice to the `eTeX` `\middle` required a complete change of method. Note that the following works with an arbitrary delimiter after `\middle`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for \dfrac 

\makeatletter

\def\p{\afterassignment\p@aux\let\next=}


\newtoks\p@toks

\def\@ybrace{\expandafter\left\expandafter\lbrace\the\p@toks\right\rbrace}
%% \def\@yparen{\expandafter\left\expandafter(\the\p@toks\right)\endgroup}
\def\@yparen{\expandafter\endgroup\expandafter\left\expandafter(\the\p@toks\right)}
%% \def\@ybrack{\expandafter\left\expandafter[\the\p@toks\right]\endgroup}
\def\@ybrack{\expandafter\endgroup\expandafter\left\expandafter[\the\p@toks\right]}

\def\p@aux{\ifx\next\bgroup
                      \def\p@tmp{\p@toks=\bgroup}%
                      \afterassignment\@ybrace
             \else
             \ifx\next(%
                   \begingroup\catcode`\)=\tw@ 
                   \def\p@tmp{\p@toks=\bgroup}%
                      \afterassignment\@yparen
             \else
             \ifx\next[%
                   \begingroup\catcode`\]=\tw@
                   \def\p@tmp{\p@toks=\bgroup}%
                      \afterassignment\@ybrack
             \else
                 \let\p@tmp\next
           \fi\fi\fi
           \p@tmp}

\makeatother


\begin{document}\thispagestyle{empty}

$\p(1) \p(\dfrac{1}{2}) \p(\dfrac{1}{2}\middle|3)$

$\p[1] \p[\dfrac{1}{2}] \p[\dfrac{1}{2}\middle|3]$

$\p{1} \p{1\middle|2} \p{\dfrac{1}{2}\middle|3}$

\end{document}
```

[image: third method]

```
$\p{1} \p{1\middle>2} \p{\dfrac{1}{2}\middle<3}$
```

[image: with < in the middle]

---

And now the method based on `mathcodes`. Perhaps I will have to think again on the case of the braces, which are treated here as in the previous method. For them only do I use a token list. The token list is because of `\middle` which makes things difficult when attempting an `\aftergroup` technique.

It is also because of `\middle` that I have to explicitely restore the `mathcodes` of `)` and `]` rather than trust it to the group which originates in the use of `\left` and `\right`. The problem is that `\middle` closes this group and then opens a second one.

Edit: there was a problem with `$ \p( ( A ) )$` and I have edited the macros so that the `mathcodes` are correctly reset. I could not use the groups created by `\left` and `\right` 'cause the `\middle`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

\def\p{\afterassignment\p@aux\let\next=}

\newtoks\p@toks

\def\@ybrace{\expandafter\left\expandafter\lbrace\the\p@toks\right\rbrace}


% To get correct nesting I added the \restore@paren and \restore@brack macros

\def\p@aux{\ifx\next\bgroup
                      \def\p@tmp{\p@toks=\bgroup}%
                      \afterassignment\@ybrace
             \else
             \ifx\next(%
                      \ifnum\mathcode`)="8000 
                           \let\restore@paren\relax
                           \def\p@tmp{\left(}%
                     \else
                       \edef\restore@paren{\mathcode`)=\the\mathcode`)\relax}%
                       \begingroup
                         \lccode`\~=`)
                         \lowercase{%
                       \endgroup
                       \def~{\right)\restore@paren}}%
                       \def\p@tmp{\mathcode`)="8000 \left(}%
                     \fi
              \else
             \ifx\next[%
                     \ifnum\mathcode`]="8000 
                           \let\restore@brack\relax
                           \def\p@tmp{\left[}%
                     \else
                       \edef\restore@brack{\mathcode`]=\the\mathcode`]\relax}%
                       \begingroup
                         \lccode`\~=`]
                         \lowercase{%
                       \endgroup
                       \def~{\right]\restore@brack}}%
                       \def\p@tmp{\mathcode`]="8000 \left[}%
                     \fi
             \else
                 \let\p@tmp\next
           \fi\fi\fi
           \p@tmp}


\makeatother
\begin{document}\thispagestyle{empty}

\delimitershortfall=-1pt

\[\p(\frac{1}{2}\p{\p{3^T:4}}\p[\p(A_B^C)]\p(\big]\middle>\big[)\middle\Vert\p[\frac{1}{2}])\]

\[\p{\p(\p[A_B^C\middle< \p{X^Y}])\middle\vert\p[\p(A_B^C\middle> \p(X^Y))]} \]
\end{document}
```

[image: nesting]

```
\[\the\mathcode`) \ \the\mathcode`] \p( \p{ \p[ \p( \p{ \p[ A ]})]})
  \the\mathcode`)\ \the\mathcode`] \]
```

[image: nesting2]

Comment: ah, I see you in fact want left and right. But this is not always a good idea. Anyway, I will modify my code.

Comment: If you can add the "middle thing", it would help. I try to compare with egreg's code. But as I am new to this stuff it's hard.

Comment: limitation: the "arbitrary" delimiter after `\middle` should not be the closing partner...

Comment: I will edit the code to move the `\endgroup` to be the first things inside `\@ybrack` and `\@yparen`, this is better.

Comment: amazingly, `$\p(\p{\dfrac{1}{2}\middle<3})$` works... but exchanging braces and parentheses gives a non working input. The reason being that the catcode of the closing parenthesis will be frozen when put into the token list used for the contents of the external braces.

Comment: Of course `\p` in the argument of a command is not guaranteed to work (or else, it's almost guaranteed not to).

Comment: @jfbu Your post help a lot to understand tex programming. I understand that the code has limitation, but this is also a lesson your post teach. Thank you.

Comment: @NicolasEssis-Breton I am truly glad it helped. I have a very strange relation to TeX "programming". It is very fascinating to have a language which is allowed to redefine (to the programmer's risk) even its most fundamental primitives. On the other hand, it has so flagrant peculiarities that I think it is really  a trap to view it as a true programming framework. Also, e-TeX brought some fundamental new tools. I don't know them well so far, so I usually stick with what I read in TeX by Topic, and more recently, the TeXBook.

Answer (score 9):

This does what you'd like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % just for \dfrac in the example

\makeatletter
\def\p{\@ifnextchar(\neb@p@parens{\@ifnextchar[\neb@p@bracket\neb@p@brace}}
\def\neb@p@brace#1{\left\{#1\right\}}
\def\neb@p@bracket[#1]{\left[#1\right]}
\def\neb@p@parens(#1){\neb@p@checkbar#1||\@nil}

\def\neb@p@checkbar#1|#2|#3\@nil{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax
    \left(#1\right)
  \else
    \left(#1\;\middle|\;#2\right)
  \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$\p(1) \p(\dfrac{1}{2})$

$\p[1] \p[\dfrac{1}{2}]$

$\p{1} \p{\dfrac{1}{2}}$

$\p(1|2) \p(\dfrac{1}{2}|3)$
\end{document}
```

[image]

This said, I recommend against using these "flexible" commands, which are error prone: different constructs should be realized with different commands.

Comment: Any advantage of the explicit checkbar command compared to thr math active bar that braket package uses?

Comment: @Aditya I see *no* advantage in using this kind of commands, so one implementation or the other is just the same.

Comment: I just discover this `\middle` thing which closes and opens a group (annoying in my approach). But your code checks only for `\middle|` ? the e-TeX doc allows `\middle<delim>`